# How can I save a custom field on ARCashSale after the Release process is complete?

Tags: acumatica

When I release a Cash Sales document, after everything verifies successfully and the GL Batch is created, I execute code which created a second GL Batch that handles other transactions related to the cash sale. After that batch is created, I want to save the second GL Batch's Ref Nbr on the Cash Sales document as well. When I try to save it, I get an error:

[image]

Here is my code overriding the normal Release process:

```
public delegate IEnumerable ReleaseDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
[PXOverride]
public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter, ReleaseDelegate baseMethod)
{
    ARCashSale cashSale = Base.Document.Current;

    PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<JournalEntry>(delegate (JournalEntry oldJournalEntry)
    {
        oldJournalEntry.RowPersisted.AddHandler<Batch>(delegate (PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
        {
            Batch oldBatch = oldJournalEntry.BatchModule.Current;

            if (oldBatch != null && isCreated == false && e.Operation == PXDBOperation.Insert && e.TranStatus == PXTranStatus.Completed)
            {
                isCreated = true;
                if (CFBSAdjustments.Select().Count > 0)
                {

                    JournalEntry newJournalEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<JournalEntry>();

                    Batch newBatch = new Batch();

                    newBatch = newJournalEntry.BatchModule.Insert(newBatch);

                    Customer customer = PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Customer.bAccountID>>>>.Select(Base, cashSale.CustomerID);
                    newBatch.Description = "Fund Entry for Cash Sales Reference " + cashSale.RefNbr;
                    newBatch.FinPeriodID = oldBatch.FinPeriodID;
                    newBatch.LedgerID = oldBatch.LedgerID;
                    newBatch.DateEntered = oldBatch.DateEntered;

                    decimal? debit = 0;
                    decimal? credit = 0;
                    foreach (CFBSCashSalesAdjustment row in CFBSAdjustments.Select())
                    {
                        GLTran tran = newJournalEntry.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Insert();

                        tran.SummPost = true;
                        tran.BranchID = cashSale.BranchID;
                        tran.TranType = GLTran.tranClass.Normal;
                        tran.TranClass = GL.Messages.RoundingDiff;
                        tran.LedgerID = newBatch.LedgerID;
                        tran.FinPeriodID = newBatch.FinPeriodID;
                        tran.TranDate = newBatch.DateEntered;
                        tran.CuryInfoID = Base.currencyinfo.Current.CuryInfoID;

                        tran.AccountID = row.Account;
                        tran.SubID = row.Subaccount;
                        tran.DebitAmt = row.DebitAmt;
                        tran.CuryDebitAmt = row.DebitAmt;
                        debit += row.DebitAmt;
                        tran.CreditAmt = row.CreditAmt;
                        tran.CuryCreditAmt = row.CreditAmt;
                        credit += row.CreditAmt;
                        tran.RefNbr = row.CashSalesRefNbr;
                        tran.TranDesc = customer.AcctCD + " - " + customer.AcctName;
                        newJournalEntry.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Update(tran);
                    }

                    newBatch = newJournalEntry.BatchModule.Update(newBatch);

                    if (GLSetup.Current.GetExtension<GLSetupExt>().UsrAutoRelease == true)
                    {
                        newJournalEntry.BatchModule.Current.Hold = false;
                        newJournalEntry.release.Press();
                    }

                    newJournalEntry.Save.Press();
                    if (isCreated)
                        isCreated = false;

                    cashSale.GetExtension<ARRegisterExt>().UsrFundBatch = newJournalEntry.BatchModule.Current.BatchNbr;
                    //Base.Document.Current.GetExtension<ARRegisterExt>().UsrFundBatch = newJournalEntry.BatchModule.Current.BatchNbr;
                    //Base.dummy_CATran.View.RequestRefresh();
                    Base.Document.Update(cashSale);
                    //TODO - Figure out why the fund batch isn't saving to the Cash Sale
                    Base.Actions.PressSave();
                    //Base.dummy_CATran.Cache.ClearQueryCache();
                    //Base.Persist(typeof(ARCashSale), PXDBOperation.Update);
                }
            }
        });

    });
    return baseMethod(adapter);
}
```

I left in all of the different methods I've tried to get the ref nbr to save. I've ever tried to add a field updated handler for the BatchNbr field and force the new number in that way, but it did not work.

EDIT: I also noticed that I cannot successfully set an extended field on the Batch DAC. For example, I have the line `newBatch.GetExtension<BatchExt>().ExtRefNbr = cashSale.RefNbr;` to set the ref nbr in that document as well, but any time I run 'NewJournal.Press.Save()' it changes the set value of the extended field to null. If anyone knows how to set the extension field, I may be able to work with that instead to go down a different path that may do what I need.

Comment: First step would be trying to find out what is modifying CATran DAC / dummy_CATran DataView. Is CFBSAdjustments DAC deriving from CATran? It seems like a custom DAC. I would try declaring a CATran_RowUpdating event, put a breakpoint in there and check the call stack to find what is modifying CATran.

Comment: CFBSAdjustments has nothing to do with CATran. I am not adjusting CATran at all. I'm assuming it is the screen and possibly the base release process of ARCashSaleEntry. EDIT: I can confirm that the CATran is updated before my custom code executes and my custom DAC does not affect CATran.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the appropriate place to perform your update is in graph ARDocumentRelease.  Try something like this....

```
public class ARDocumentReleaseExtension : PXGraphExtension<ARDocumentRelease>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        ARSetup setup = Base.arsetup.Current;
        Base.ARDocumentList.SetProcessDelegate(
            delegate (List<BalancedARDocument> list)
            {
                List<ARRegister> newlist = new List<ARRegister>(list.Count);
                foreach (BalancedARDocument doc in list)
                {
                    newlist.Add(doc);
                }
                ARDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(newlist, true);
                CreateSecondBatch(newlist);
                    
            }
        );
        Base.ARDocumentList.SetProcessCaption(PX.Objects.AR.Messages.Release);
        Base.ARDocumentList.SetProcessAllCaption(PX.Objects.AR.Messages.ReleaseAll);
    }

    private void CreateSecondBatch(List<ARRegister> docs)
    {
        foreach(BalancedARDocument register in docs)
        {
            if (register.DocType == ARDocType.CashSale)
            {
               //create the second batch and assign the 2nd ref nbr to the cash sale user field
            }
        }
     }
}
```